# R: parallel process several rows together using doParallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, dataframe

I would like to do some parallel processing on a large data frame in R using the `doParallel` package. Lets call the data frame `mydata`. I want to iterate over the data frame by rows, so something like

```
foreach(x=iter(mydata, by='row')) %dopar%{
    ... do stuff ...
}
```

However, thats not quite right because in each loop I need to have access to several rows. Lets say the variable `idx` contains the information of which rows need to be processed together. Lets say `idx` is a matrix that looks like

```
1  2  3
10 12 14
4  7  9
...
```

where each row indicates the rows of `mydata` that need to be processed together. How can I do this using the `doParallel` package?

EDIT: I see that I can send "blocks" of the data.frame using `iblkcol` is there a way to send non-consecutive blocks of my choosing?

EDIT: I ended up using a custom iteraor:

```
> data <- data.frame(A=sample(letters,10),B=rnorm(10))
> data
   A          B
1  z  0.5105797
2  h  1.2559502
3  a  0.9697254
4  n -1.4189076
5  e -0.5800640
6  b  0.2907486
7  q -2.4414012
8  d  1.8146928
9  v  0.2510003
10 x -0.2011185
> idx <- list(c(1,2),c(4,5),c(3,6,7),c(8,9,10))
> 
> library(iterators)
> 
> ialn <- function( x, idx){
+   it <- iter(idx)
+   nextEl <- function(){
+     n <- nextElem(it)
+     x[n,]
+   }
+   obj <- list(nextElem=nextEl)
+   class(obj)<- c('ialn','abstractiter','iter')
+   obj
+ }
> 
> 
> it <- ialn(data,idx)
> nextElem(it)
  A         B
1 z 0.5105797
2 h 1.2559502
> nextElem(it)
  A         B
4 n -1.418908
5 e -0.580064
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps splitting mydata into a list based on

```
apply(idx,1,function(idx) list(mydata[idx,]) )
```

and then sending that list through the foreach?

Either that or a [custom iterator](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iterators/vignettes/writing.pdf) that gets the data based on the row indexes.

Comment: Thanks! Using a custom iterator I was able to get what I wanted.